# Configuration Names in a project file question?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

Hello can some please explain to me what are the differences between this configuration names in a project, are there difference in the build output?. Unfortunately I am only familliar with the Debug and Release, so please any help would be appreciated Thanks

```
Debug|Win32,
```

Release|Win32,
Release MinDependency|Win32,
Release MinSize|Win32,
Unicode Debug|Win32, 
Unicode Release MinDependency|Win32,
Unicode Release MinSize|Win32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the kind of configuration names you get for an ATL project, back in the Visual Studio 6 days.  The names hint at the selected settings:

- MinDependency - embeds ATL in the final binary instead of relying on atl.dll
- MinSize - uses the "Minimize size" optimizer option, instead of "Maximize speed"
- Unicode - makes all strings utf-16, matching the operating system use.

This kind of fine-grained control doesn't make make sense anymore these days.  Unicode should always be your choice, especially for ATL.  You'll want to embed ATL, size is pretty irrelevant today.  The optimizer setting is "Maximize speed" these days, /O2 in VS2008

Comment: Wow again very clear and prompt response. Thank you Very much now I Understand. Very much appreciated!